Why move_uploaded_file fails with inappropriate ioctl?
I have a very very strange problem.
I am using the jQuery-File-Upload from blueimp for uploading files. I use it for years on Windows and Linux.
Recently I used a new server (with AlmaLinux). Previously I was using PHP 5.6 and now I am using PHP 7.4 on this new server.
When I upload a file I receive this warning :

move_uploaded_file(/path_to_webroot/img/image.jpg): failed to open stream: Inappropriate ioctl for device in /path_to_webroot/php/UploadHandler.php on line 1079

I tried to upload the same image with a very basic upload form (without using jQuery-File-Upload) and the move_uploaded_file was successful so it is not a permission problem.
The strange thing comes now!
I found a workaround!
if ($uploaded_file && is_uploaded_file($uploaded_file)) {
    // multipart/formdata uploads (POST method uploads)
    if ($append_file) {
        file_put_contents(
            $file_path,
            fopen($uploaded_file, 'r'),
            FILE_APPEND
        );
    } else {
        $toto = print_r($file_path, true); //Workaround: this line avoids to the next line to fail
        move_uploaded_file($uploaded_file, $file_path); //this is the line failing
    }
}

I don't understand why doing a print_r() helps to succeed moving file. Even if I do a var_dump it helps. If I just do an echo it doesn't work.
I would like to avoid to do this workaround for fixing my problem because it's not a solution for me. Someone has an idea why move_uploaded_file is failing? Maybe can I change something in php.ini configuration?
